# Missing required get parameter angular 4

Tags: angular, http, typescript, observable

I'm getting the console log as follows: "'Missing required 'page' parameter".

I'm trying to set it as the parameters in my get request, and it seems to work, as I can get the console to print out the params as an array.

What am I missing?
Photo of the console: [image: See this]

Thanks!

Service:

```
export class StoriesService implements OnInit {

  private apiUrl = 'https://dev-api.byrd.news/v1/stories';

  constructor(private http: Http) {
    console.log("Yo! Stories!")
  }

  ngOnInit() { }

  getToken() {
    return Observable.fromPromise(firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdToken(true)
      .then((idToken) => {
        return idToken;
      }))
  }


  getData(page: string, feed: string, hits: string): Observable<any> {
    return this.getToken()
      .flatMap(idToken => {
        let headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('user_token', idToken);
        let params = new HttpParams()
          .set('page', page)
          .set('feed', feed)
          .set('hits', hits);
        let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers, params: params });
        // console.log(this.idToken, options);
        console.log("Token: " + idToken);
        console.log(headers, params);
        return this.http
          .get(this.apiUrl, { params, headers })
          .map((response: Response) => {
            console.log("Breakthrough!")
            return response.json() || {};
          })
      })
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }

  private handleError(error: Response) {
    return Observable.throw(error.statusText);
  }
```

Component:

```
  getStories() {
    this.storiesService.getData('0', 'latest', '6')
    .subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data);
      console.log("Ikke mere data")
    })
  }
```

Edit:
This is the URL I get. The params look a little funny to me, or is it just because its unparsed?

"https://dev-api.byrd.news/v1/stories?updates=%7B%22param%22:%22page%22,%22value%22:%220%22,%22op%22:%22s%22%7D&updates=%7B%22param%22:%22feed%22,%22value%22:%22latest%22,%22op%22:%22s%22%7D&updates=%7B%22param%22:%22hits%22,%22value%22:%226%22,%22op%22:%22s%22%7D&cloneFrom=%7B%22updates%22:null,%22cloneFrom%22:null,%22encoder%22:%7B%7D,%22map%22:null%7D&encoder=%7B%7D&map=null"

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the server is just sending that to you. The problem then isn't with Angular, it's with the request you're making.

EDIT: The request does look a bit weird. The docs for `RequestOptions` seem to say that `params` should be a `URLSearchParams`, not an `HttpParams`. Maybe that's the problem.

Comment: So what do you suggest mate?